# Why won't his syntactically correct program compile on the Xcode IDE with llvm compiler?

Tags: c++, llvm

github repository: https://github.com/d-parkinson/C-practice-file.git

> *Created 4/04/2016 by Darren Parkinson.
>       This is a two player simulation fight game between two characters:
>                                             a Villian and a Hero
>                                 Each Character has four features respectively:
>                         Name(string), health(integer), kick(integer), punch(integer)*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

> *Superclass holding details of regarding the features of the characters*

```
class Character{
public:
    std::string name;
    static int health;
    int kick;
    int punch;
    Character(std::string name, int health, int kick, int punch){
        this -> health = health;
        this -> name = name;
        this -> kick = kick;
        this -> punch = punch;
    }
    ~Character(){}
};
```

> *Subclass displaying features of heroes*

```
class Hero : public Character{
public:
    Hero(std::string name, int health, int kick, int punch) : Character(name, health, kick, punch){
        std::cout << name << ": Joker giving trouble again" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Hero(){}
};
```

> *Subclass displaying features of villians*

```
class Villian : public Character{
public:
    Villian(std::string name, int health, int kick, int punch) : Character(name, health, kick, punch){
        std::cout << name << ": Hey there hehehe" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Villian(){}
};
```

> *Functions illustrating actions between both villain and hero classes*

```
void VillianPunch(Hero *hero, Villian *villian){
    hero -> health -= villian -> punch;
    std::cout << villian -> name << ": take this(punch)" << std::endl;
}
void VillianKick(Hero *hero, Villian *villian){
    hero -> health -= villian -> kick;
    std::cout << villian -> name << ": take this(kick)" << std::endl;
}
void HeroPunch(Hero *hero, Villian *villian){
    villian -> health -= hero -> punch;
    std::cout << hero -> name << ": take this(punch)" << std::endl;
}
void HeroKick(Hero *hero, Villian *villian){
    villian -> health -= hero -> kick;
    std::cout << hero -> name << ": take this(kick)" << std::endl;
}
```

> *The main functions*

```
    int main(void){
    Hero *batman;
    Villian *joker;
    joker = new Villian("Joker",1000,90,63);
    batman = new Hero("Batman",1100,93,60);
    std::cout << "Fight!!!" << std::endl;
```

> *Do function simulating the fight between Villian and Hero*

```
    do{
        HeroPunch(batman, joker);
        VillianPunch(batman, joker);
        VillianKick(batman, joker);
        HeroKick(batman, joker);
        if(batman -> health <= 0)
            std::cout << joker -> name << ": You won't catch me today hehehe" << std::endl;
        else if(joker -> health <= 0)
            std::cout << batman -> name << ": How many times do I have to defeat you" << std::endl;
    }while((batman -> health > 0) & (joker -> health > 0));
    delete joker;
    delete batman;
    return 0;
}
```

> *I'm a new c++ programmer, practicing with git and stack overflow*
>   Error messages below:
>
> "Character::health",referenced from:
>
> VillianPunch(Hero*, Villian*) in Game-simulation.o
>
> VillianKick(Hero*, Villian*) in Game-simulation.o
>
> HeroPunch(Hero*, Villian*) in Game-simulation.o
>
> HeroKick(Hero*, Villian*) in Game-simulation.o
>
> _main in Game-simulation.o
>
> Character::Character(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, int, int,
>   int) in Game-simulation.o ld:
>
> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Comment: You need to include the compiler error messages in your question. Also, the actual code would be better, rather than something that has processed the comments into HTML.

Comment: stack overflow won't allow me to enter the whole code

Comment: Your question was about compiler errors. You need to at least include said errors in the question and the associated lines of code.

Comment: I updated the question with errors stated, based on my syntax everything is alright, those are the error displayed

Comment: The 'health' variable should not be static.

Answer (score 0):

The code *did* compile; the error message is from the linker.  (As to why the linker couldn’t find the symbol it complained about, that’s presumably somewhere in the interaction between the code, the Game-simulation library, and the Standard Library, and I won’t speculate.)